# Non-static method 'onResume' Android Studio

Tags: android

I want to use a `WebView` for **Youtube**. When I try to compile it, I get this error "non-static method `onResume` & `onPause` cannot be referenced from a **static context**".

I have tried to use a rootView, but it didn't work ='(

```
public class vod extends Fragment {

    public static final String TAG = "vod";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vod, container, false);


        WebView wv = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView2);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            }
        });
        wv.setWebViewClient(
                new WebViewClient() {
                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                        view.loadUrl(url);
                        return false;
                    }
                });
        wv.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/user/XX");
        wv.addJavascriptInterface(new WebSocketFactory(wv), "WebSocketFactory");
        return rootView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        WebView.onResume();
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        WebView.onPause();
    }
}
```

I don't know how to resolve this. I need your help =)
Thank you =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your **wv** variable as class member and use it then like this:

```
private WebView wv;

// onCreateView ...

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    wv.onResume();
}
```

And same with onPause...

Comment: Thank you, but my app crash **logcat** :      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.webkit.WebView.onResume()' on a null object reference
            at com.xx.xx.vod.onResume(vod.java:61)

Comment: That's a different question. Create a new question for this.

Comment: Make sure you have view with id **webView2** in your **vod** layout file

Comment: Yes, in my VOD Layout, my WeBiew is "webView2"

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call the non-static methods `onResume` and `onPause` from WebView, but are accessing them in a static way. Either way, what you are doing makes no sense. Calling lifecycle methods manually is unnecessary and should be avoided. You can get rid of your `onResume` and `onPause` methods if you are only calling super.

If you want to call onResume and onPause from the Fragment, then use

`wv.onResume` and `wv.onPause`.

I modified your code below to solve your problem:

```
public class vod extends Fragment {

    public static final String TAG = "vod";
    private WebView wv;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vod, container, false);


        wv = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView2);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            }
        });
        wv.setWebViewClient(
                new WebViewClient() {
                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                        view.loadUrl(url);
                        return false;
                    }
                });
        wv.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/user/XX");
        wv.addJavascriptInterface(new WebSocketFactory(wv), "WebSocketFactory");
        return rootView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        wv.onResume();
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        wv.onPause();
    }
}
```

Also, class names should start with a capital letter, by convention. So call your Fragment `Vod` instead of `vod`.

Comment: In Android Studio, he don't want when i use a CAP in first letter.

Comment: Show the warning. I find this hard to believe.